# How to display products belonging to one user backpack laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

In my VendorsCrudController i make relation 1-n:
```

````
$this->crud->setModel('App\User');
$this->crud->addField([   // Address
            'name' => 'vendor',
            'type' => 'select',
            'entity' => 'vendor', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => 'App\Dispensary',
        ]);
```
In User modal have method:
```
public function dispensaries() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Dispensary');
    }

In Dispensary model:
public function vendor() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
````

```
Table structure:
(users)
id: 1, name: Someone
id: 2, name: Someone2
(dispensaries)
id: 1, user_id: 1, name: SomeDispensary
id: 2, user_id: 2, name: SomeDispensary

How to display products belonging to one user. Now I get all the products for one user

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways of filtering a CRUD table:

- you can force the results to always be filtered using addClause ([take a look here under ADVANCED QUERIES](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-full-api#section-often-used)) ; this method is useful, for example, to only let a user see his own items (ex: `$this->crud->addClause('where', 'user_id', '=', backpack_user()->id);`);
- you can insert a filter above the CRUD table to help your admin filter the results however he likes ([take a look at filters](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/filters));

Hope it helps.